# XDK 1199 build failed info for Windows Phone cordova 3.x -

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8, intel-xdk

I was wondering if there was any way to see "Build Failed" error messages for a build process for XDK (1199). I've successfully built for Android using 3.x cordova. As well I can build the windows phone version using "legacy" 2.9 cordova. However when I copy the exact details from the 2.9 information to the project build details (at the front of XDK) and add the different screen size images, I get a build error trying to build for 3.x cordova. Is there any way to see the error message for the build to try to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I've read somewhere that this error is related to App Name, which cannot have upper case letters on it. apparently, it only occurs on Windows builds

So, try a full lowercase app name and rebuild!